# How to beat Level 25 in Flip Palace?

Tags: logical-deduction

[Flip Palace](https://armorgames.com/flip-palace-game/19183?tag-referral=minimalism) is a minimalist game developed by 08jack where you flip into the walls and solve puzzles.

The goal of Flip Palace (stolen from the description):

> flip into the walls, solve puzzles

This is Level 25:

[image]

I'll explain what the arrows mean later.

Now, while I have beaten this level before, I never really remember how to beat it due to how confusing it is. Here is what I remember of how to do it:

1. The left arrow switches your gravity so your character is facing left. The up arrow switches your gravity so your character is upside down. The keys do exactly what you think they do, but they can be collected infinitely.

We need to avoid the left arrow right away. Here's a screenshot explaining why:

[image]

Here's a step-by-step explanation of what's going on:

1. Go into the left arrow, which makes you fall to the left.
2. Flip into the wall.
3. Fall down to the right.
4. Flip into the wall to get the purple key, which is basically the key needed to beat Level 25.
5. Flip again, although it doesn't really matter what you do from here, because since Step 3 you've basically been softlocked.

---

2. So obviously we do this (collect the Yellow key):

[image]

3. Then we can flip into the wall and then fall onto the other side (since the game is played on a Möbius strip)

[image]

Now this seems to be where I always get stuck for some reason.

I know that if I haven't collected the yellow key or I've collected it $2n$ times for $n\in\mathbb N$, if I touch the left arrow, I'm basically softlocked, however I only think this happens if I haven't already collected the purple key.

I remember having using the up arrow once to beat the level, but I don't remember when I used it.

So my question is, how do I beat Level 25 in Flip Palace?

Comment: "the game is played on a Möbius strip" if both directions wrap around, and nothing gets flipped as you go around, the game is on a *torus*.

Comment: When you say "flip into the wall", you mean that the character stands on the same surface but mirrored on it and the gravity inverts as well, correct?  So effectively if the character is in a grey corridor with black walls and flips, they are then in the black corridor with grey walls.

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem Ah my bad I kinda forgot the difference between Möbius Strip and torus tbh

Comment: I played around with the game a bit.  The playing field is sort of like a torus, except you can only wrap around in the direction of gravity.  (This is basically a cylinder until you reach levels with horizontal arrows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer requires two reasonable assumptions: you can jump *across* a whole "block", but not *up*, and the end goal is the white diamond.

To reach the goal, the gray gravity must be facing left. However, there's no way to fall into either the gray room or its black ledge unless the purple key is active. Additionally, if the orange key is active while the left arrow is claimed, then it will set the *black gravity* left, which makes the gray gravity *right*.

But claiming the purple key from the starting state is impossible, as you showed!

> What we must do is claim the orange key before touching the left arrow, in order to *claim the purple key from the other side* and not get stuck!

> Starting from your last image, claim the left arrow, then fall left and flip into the purple key. Without flipping back, fall right and move up to reclaim the up arrow, then deactivate the orange key. Move right, flip, fall down, and reclaim the left arrow, and you should fall right next to the goal.

Comment: Ah yes, that was the solution. I think the problem might have been that I'm good at speedrunning, so while I did memorize the level, I just didn't do so with my brain. I really need to get out of that habit.